# Ignore the <B> &</B> when extracting text from HTML

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwcbL.png)

Anyone know how to remove the  ?

Comment: Please post your code as text.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `<B></B>` like this

```
import re
a = ['New Orleans', '<B>Carolina</B>', 'Miami', 'Buffalo']
b = []
filter = re.compile('<.*?>|&([a-z0-9]+|#[0-9]{1,6}|#x[0-9a-f]{1,6});')
for i in a:
    i = re.sub(filter, '', i)
    b.append(i)
print(b)
```

output:

```
['New Orleans', 'Carolina', 'Miami', 'Buffalo']
```

Comment: Try this with `'Buffalo'` in your list.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, check my updated answer